# Google Play Protect shows warning when installing an APK

Tags: installation, apk, google-play-protect

I have tried signing the app with the Android debug key and also I have tried signing the APK with my private key (whose APK is present in Play Store) but still used to get this warning.

[image]

I don't want to disable the Play Protect (as this is not the solution).

When I make clones of the same APK, for example making 10 clones of 1 same APK and every APK with the new unique package name, out of those 10 clones, I used to see the Play Protect warning in only 4-5 APKs and the rest of APKs used to be good (it's not the issue of the package name).  I have also tried to sign the APK with Apk Easy Tool, but still the same issue.

Everything was working well, but I started facing this issue of Google Play Protect warnings since Nov 2021.

Can anyone please tell me how can I fix the fake Google Play protection warning shown in the APK while installing the app?

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that this site focus on Android end-users and power-users having issues. So while we might probably give suggestions to hide/disable/reduce the frequency of the pop-up/scan (if possible), we can't help issues caused when developing an app, like re-signing the app, etc., at least without knowing more details about this app.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think this is a fake Google Play Protect dialog? A malicious app would just upload the app without asking.

"Send unknown apps to Google" is an official feature of Google Play protect

> Send unknown apps to Google If you choose to install apps from unknown
> sources outside of the Google Play Store, turning on the “Improve
> harmful app detection” setting will allow Google Play Protect to send
> unknown apps to Google to protect you from harmful apps.
>
> 1. Open the Google Play Store app Google Play.
> 2. At the top right, tap the profile icon.
> 3. Tap Play Protect and then Settings.
> 4. Turn Improve harmful app detection on or off.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2812853?hl=en